# Weighted Set covering problem with a fixed number of colors

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, optimization

I have a set of elements U = {1, 2, .... , n} and a set S of k sets whose union form the whole universe. Each of these sets is associated with a cost.

I have a fixed number of colors, C = {1 , 2, ... , m}. Some of the sets mentioned above interfere with each other. I cannot assign same color to both those sets together.

I want to pick the sets and color them from my available color list in the following way:

**Objective: Minimize the total cost of the selected sets

Constraints:

1. All elements of the universe are covered
2. No two sets that interfere with each other is assigned the same color**

If the second constraint, i.e., coloring constraint, is taken out, the problem reduces to standard weighted set covering problem. I can solve that using a greedy manner. For example, greedy unweighted set covering will work in the following way: -- 1. pick the set with the highest number of elements at first, 2. Remove that set and the associated elements from the universe, 3. Repeat step 1 until all elements of the universe are covered.

But the coloring constraint in the presence of interference among sets and a fixed number of colors complicates the issue.

For example, let's assume,

U = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

There are three sets, {1, 2, 3}; {2, 3, 4, 5} ; {4, 5}.

Assume {2, 3, 4, 5} interferes with both {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5}. {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5} do not interfere with each other. Assume that there is only one color in the system.

A standard greedy unweighted set coloring solution will pick {2, 3, 4, 5} at first and {1, 2, 3} in the second round. But that is an infeasible solution to my problem since they interfere with each other and I have only one color in my system. A feasible solution will be the selection of {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5}.

I wonder how I can minimize the total cost while meeting the color constraint. Any hint on the unweighted version of the problem (where all sets have equal cost) will be very helpful, too.

Thanks,

Nazmul

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_i$ be the $i$'th member of $S$.  Take indicator variables $x_{ij} = 1$ if $S_i$ is selected and assigned colour $j$, $0$ otherwise.  Then you can formulate this as an integer linear programming problem:

minimize $\sum_i \sum_j {\rm cost}_i x_{ij}$
subject to

$$\eqalign{ \sum_j x_{ij} \le 1 & \text{ for all } i\cr
            \sum_{\{i: u \in S_i\}} \sum_j x_{ij} \ge 1 & \text{ for all } u \in U\cr
            x_{ij} + x_{i'j} \le 1 & \text{ for all } j \text{ whenever } S_i \cap S_{i'} \ne \emptyset\cr
\text{all } & x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}}$$